# ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to fetch github repository on Jenkins. Jenkins is installed on CentOS. I have created a pipeline. Here is what I have tried.

```
node{
    stage 'Checkout code'
        git credentialsId: <credentialsId>, url: <gitUrl>
}
```

Also I have tried this syntax:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Git') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: <credentialsId>, url: <gitUrl>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Global tool Configuration, I have set "Path to Git executable" to /usr/libexec/git-core ('git --exec-path' command gives me this)
Also tried /usr/bin/git ('which git' command gives me this)

I am always getting this error:
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: It is working when I installed Jenkins on windows machine. All settings are the same.

Comment: Check if you have access to Github by fetch public repo or curl.

Comment: I was able to do that on windows machine (Jenkins on windows) with the same settings and the same git repository.